# How to use Bitrise build message when deploying to HockeyApp

Tags: build, continuous-integration, hockeyapp, bitrise

How can I use the Bitrise build message (look at the image bellow) as a message when deploying to HockeyApp?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**$BITRISE_GIT_MESSAGE** is the exact variable for this purpose! Thanks to the Bitrise support!